# Displaying data from a variable in page.cs to page.aspx in html

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a combo box and a label in an aspx page which fires an event when I select any value. Based upon the value selected, the function in code behind retrieves a value from the Database. I would like to display this value in the label. Please help. Also if you can also guide me on resources where I can learn more on this. Thanks in advance.
Rajiv

Comment: Is this Homework?  Please post some code, what you have tried so far to achieve this.

Comment: No, I am working on a web portal and I also want to learn. I have the HTML Design and Layout ready. I know a bit of ADO.net. Just want to know how I can integrate the code behind and HTML. Thanks

Comment: Please show  some code part

Comment: [Model binding](https://www.google.com/search?q=aspx+model+binding&oq=aspx+model&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3768j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)...

Comment: here is the cs code:
 protected void cmbPoojaName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string poojaname = cmbPoojaName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();

            using(con=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRKBS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sqlpr = new SqlDataAdapter("select Rate from v_PoojaDetails where PoojaName ='" + cmbPoojaName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim() + "' and DeityName = '" + cmbDeityName.DataTextField.Trim() + "'", con);

in the HTML i have a <td><% What to add here %></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectedIndexChange` event.
In the handler which gets created automatically use below code:

```
labelid.Text = comboBoxId.SelectedItem.ToString();
```